# onScroll is not a function error with useNatveDriver and ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-typescript, react-native-scrollview, react-native-animatable

I want to add a collapsable header in my Application.
I created a separated component for the Header view.

```
interface Props{
    userData: UserDetails | null
    scrollY: Animated.Value
}
    
const HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT = sizeProportionHeight(320)
const HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT = sizeProportionHeight(142)

const CollapsableHeader : React.FC<Props> = ({userData, scrollY}) => {
    
   const headerHeight = scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT-HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [HEADER_EXPANDED_HEIGHT, HEADER_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return(
        <Animated.View style={{height: headerHeight, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, position:'absolute', top:0, left: 0}}/>
    )
}

export default CollapsableHeader
```

I my main page I added the header as such:

```
interface Props{
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<MainParamList,'HomeScreen'>
    route: RouteProp<MainParamList,'HomeScreen'>
}

interface HeaderState {
    scrollY: Animated.Value   
}

interface HomeScreenState {
    header: HeaderState
}

const HomeScreen : React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }) => {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState<HomeScreenState>({header: {scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)}})

    return (
        <View  style={styles.container}>
            <CollapsableHeader userData={null} 
                               scrollY={state.header.scrollY}/>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={[styles.scrollContainer]}
                        onScroll={Animated.event(
                            [{
                                nativeEvent: {
                                    contentOffset: {
                                        y: state.header.scrollY
                                    }
                                    
                                },
                            }],
                            {
                                useNativeDriver:true
                            }
                            
                        )}
                        scrollEventThrottle={16}>
/// Scrollable content
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

However if I try to scroll I get an error stating

```
this.props.onScroll is not a function. (In 'this.props.onScroll(e)', 'this.props.onScroll' is an instance of AnimatedEvent)
```

If I remove the `useNativeDriver: true` the error disappears, but instead I get a warning saying that I'm missing `useNativeDriver`.

How can I correctly use this collapsable animation?

Answer (score 6):

Using `nativeDriver` means we can send everything about the animation to native before it has even started and allows native code to perform the animation on the UI thread without having to go through the bridge on every frame.

Not everything you can do with Animated is currently supported in Native Animated. The main limitation is that you can only animate non-layout properties, things like `transform` and `opacity` will work but Flexbox and position properties won't.

So as you can see `width` and `height` aren't supported by `nativeDriver`, you can just disable it.

```
useNativeDriver: false
```

No need to completely remove it.

**Note**: Change `ScrollView` to `Animated.ScrollView` too: